# How can i comunicate between two devices without cloud server?

Tags: flutter, mobile, geolocation, share

I tried develop an mobile app its share my current geolocate without cloud server between two devices whos install same apps .This devices posible using internet and it have cellphone number.
So i set fullter and add google map flugin. And i marked my current geolocate in google map also. But i stuck in issue.

"How can i send my current gelocate data to another device whitout any cloud server?"

I consider socketio. But i can't find way how can get correct device address
that receive device.

```
   private Socket mSocket;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("How can i get this url");
        mSocket.connect();
      } catch(URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

Or what is best way from this issue?